# Bootstrap image background to cover full width inside the container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Since yesterday I am trying to get the effect that image was outside left and text div was still in container grid. I cannot use container-fluid because then text div gets fluid, and I do not want it to cover the full width on right side. Any tips?

Code: https://www.codeply.com/go/vTLom0BFoh

Comment: image is cropped? is that your issue

Answer (score 1):

**Use   `m-0` to `container` what means the margin will be 0px**
Bootstrap 4 spacing:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

```css
.left {
  z-index: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.left:before {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480365150985-65998f933ef6?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=700&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container   m-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 left"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2>Title section</h2>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
        voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me if that what you mean

Comment: This is really good, but when I do it this way, the whole container starts at 0 and with txt div it has a big right margin and is not in one line with the previous sections. You can see it here:

https://www.codeply.com/go/vTLom0BFoh

Comment: so use `ml-1` instead `m-0` what means only left side

Comment: unfortunately ml-1 works the same as m-0 all cointainer starts at 0. I need the img to start 0 and txt dvi start normal in the center site, as in the basic container col-6.

Comment: Is it help you?

Comment: Hi unfortunately, but no, all time txt div is not at the right edge of the grid look ther 1 element is your code

https://www.codeply.com/go/vTLom0BFoh

most tellingly I want it to look like my code, but with a picture starting like in your code. Thank you that you want to help

Comment: try to set `mt-3` to title div

Comment: can you explain me with pic ?

Comment: because you dont add to second `conteiner` `ml-0`

Comment: you can also set padding-top to second :https://jsfiddle.net/78sk5xb4/3/

Comment: look please wireframe 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BFwg.jpg

Only 1 section have image with ml-0 all other sections are supposed to be normally in grid bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

if your image is cropped you can use

```
.left:before{background-size: cover;}
```

but make sure you are using proper image in order to look like it wont compress

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the problem. I want the image not to cut off on the container but it was until the end of the screen.

Comment: if you want full image background you can apply col-sm-12 for main div

Comment: Not exactly, I'm trying to do something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImyQL.jpg

Comment: then one short method is there, apply fluid div instead of container and use padding-right: 12%; for your right text div and the result will look like your image

Answer (score 0):

Image is not shown fully then you use .left:before { background-size: contain; } or .left:before{ background-size: cover; } in CSS it can solve your problem

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the problem. I want the image not to cut off on the container but it was until the end of the screen.

Comment: You can use background-image to parent class and content div use class pull-right to display right side of image

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `container-fluid`, and then manually style the right column so that it only takes half of the width of a non-fluid container.

Here's a working demo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.left {
  z-index: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.left:before {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480365150985-65998f933ef6?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=700&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
}

/*
$grid-breakpoints: (
xs: 0,
sm: 576px,
md: 768px,
lg: 992px,
xl: 1200px
);

$container-max-widths: (
sm: 540px,
md: 720px,
lg: 960px,
xl: 1140px
);
*/

@media(min-width: 576px) {
  .col-not-fluid {
    flex-basis: 270px;
    max-width: 270px;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .col-not-fluid {
    flex-basis: 360px;
    max-width: 360px;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 992px) {
  .col-not-fluid {
    flex-basis: 480px;
    max-width: 480px;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-not-fluid {
    flex-basis: 570px;
    max-width: 570px;
  }
}
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 left"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-not-fluid">
      <h2>Title section</h2>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
        voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: solution adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63457924/450398).